# getting erro as "connected to an idle instance" oracle

Tags: oracle

I have two oracle DB's, but I am getting "idle instance in primary db as below
Also db1 is working fine.

```
[oracle@db1 ~]$ export ORACLE_SID=SPM1
[oracle@db1 ~]$ sqlplus '/as sysdba'

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Aug 20 12:57:25 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.
```

Comment: You didn't start the instance. Run `startup` to get it up and running. More details in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/start.htm#ADMIN004

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whenever oracle process are getting hanged for any database instatnces, then type of error will occur.
to resolve this, we need to hard reboot to database server. i did the same and its resolved.